# password_reset_confirm.html and password_reser_complete.html in not rendering in django

Tags: django

I have implemented password reset functionality in Django it working fine but when I open account recovery link from the Gmail browser redirects me to Django's built-in password_reset_confirm page I want it to redirect me to my custom password_reset_confirm.html
urls.py code

```
app_name="accounts"
urlpatterns=[
path('password_reset/',auth_views.PasswordResetView.as_view( template_name='password_reset.html', success_url=reverse_lazy('accounts:password_reset_done')),name='password_reset'),
path('password_reset_done/', auth_views.PasswordResetDoneView.as_view(template_name='password_reset_done.html'), name='password_reset_done'),
path('password_reset_confirm/<uidb64>/<token>/',auth_views.PasswordResetConfirmView.as_view(template_name='password_reset_confirm.html',success_url=reverse_lazy('accounts:password_reset_complete')),name='password_reset_confirm.html'),
path('password_reset_complete/', auth_views.PasswordResetCompleteView.as_view(template_name='password_reset_complete.html'), name='password_reset_complete'),
]
```

I also want to check if the email id entered by the user is exist or not. if the user's entered email-id does not exist then a message should pop up on the password_reset.html page "this email-id does not exist"

Answer (score 0):

I noticed that some of your `urls` are wrong. As you know `django` has a built in system to recover password. So you need to respect the paths.

```py
from django.urls import path, include
from django.contrib.auth import views as auth_views

    path('password-reset/',
         auth_views.PasswordResetView.as_view(
             template_name='accounts/password_reset.html'
         ),
         name='accounts-recover'),
    path('password-reset/done/',
         auth_views.PasswordResetDoneView.as_view(
             template_name='accounts/password_reset_done.html'
         ),
         name='password_reset_done'),
    path('password-reset-confirm/<uidb64>/<token>/',
         auth_views.PasswordResetConfirmView.as_view(
             template_name='accounts/password_reset_confirm.html'
         ),
         name='password_reset_confirm'),
    path('password-reset-complete/',
         auth_views.PasswordResetCompleteView.as_view(
             template_name='accounts/password_reset_complete.html'
         ),
         name='password_reset_complete'),
```

Please make sure you have all your custom templates under `accounts/templates/accounts` so django can find the `html` you want to render.

About your second request:

> check if the email id entered by the user is exist or not

you'll need to read [django docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.0/) it's possible but you'll need to create some logic. Also, I wouldn't recommend giving any feedback other than "Mail sent" in those pages, it can be a security flaw and data leak in your app.

Good luck

Comment: after implementing this solution I got an error `NoReverseMatch at /accounts/user_login
Reverse for 'password_reset' not found. 'password_reset' is not a valid view function or pattern name.`

Comment: check your html template for links. You're trying to send the user to a page that you don't have. also check this video, it might help: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=3aVqWaLjqS4

Comment: I have solved `NoReverseMatch ` error by setting the success URL to password_reset view but still, it redirects me to the Django's default password_reset_confirm.html page

Comment: I have tried everything but it redirects me Django default template page again and again

Comment: default template url is     `http://127.0.0.1:8000/reset/MTA/set-password/`

Comment: It still redirects me on Django default page even I have removed password_reset_confirm view It don't show me any error like `password_reset_confirm is not found or ect.`

Comment: I think I have to drop this idea to use Django inbuilt password-reset system